# Using glob() to display images from a directory while echo'ing a unique first image

Tags: php, loops, directory, glob

I am quite new to PHP and I did not want to ask anything here until I absolutely could not find a way to do this.

I have a situation where I would like to use PHP to read and display images from a directory but I would like the first image read to be echo'd uniquely

My current code as follows:

```
$imageDir = "img/landMarks/carousel/";
$images = glob($imageDir.'*.jpg');
foreach ($images as $image){
echo '<div class="item">'."\r\n\t\t";
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt=""></div>'."\r\n\t";}
```

Just a simple directory pull and echo with formatting.

This will be for a BootStrap carousel and unfortunately the first image in line has to have `<div class="item active">` or the whole thing fails.

So to reiterate, the first image pulled needs to be `<div class="item active">` while the rest need to be `<div class="item">`

I think I went through an entire pack of cigarettes wracking my brain around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a flag for that. hope to help.(-:

```
$imageDir = "img/landMarks/carousel/";
$images = glob($imageDir.'*.jpg');
$flag=1;
foreach ($images as $image){
echo '<div class="item' .($flag?' active':''). '">'.PHP_EOL."\t\t";
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt=""></div>'.PHP_EOL."\t";
$flag=0;
}
```

Comment: New to StackOverflow, don't have any rep to upvote. But I'll definitely accept your answer.

Comment: Also, PHP_EOL. Is this a preferred way to do a new line rather than \r\n?

Comment: @SeRosiS - yes and also using `'` is more faster than `"` . try to use `"` when only needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start to implement this into my current projects.

Comment: Just a friendly heads-up, The `'` around the `\t` in your answer results in the `\t` being printed inside the echo alongside everything else, negating the tabs.

Comment: Again, thanks a bunch. You saved me a huge headache of having to make a placeholder image. That would have been ugly.

Comment: Again, your welcome. please think and ask any question you think you have.(I mean ask and answer questions to gain reputation).

Answer (score 1):

How about using a for loop instead of a foreach loop. When index == 0 you can add "active" to your div's class.

**Note** *I didn't run this code- but it should give you the right idea.*

```
$imageDir = "img/landMarks/carousel/";
$images = glob($imageDir.'*.jpg');
for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++){
       //If the index is 0, it's the first image.
       $class = ($i == 0) ? 'item active' : 'item';

       //Dynamically change your div's class
       echo "<div class='$class'>\r\n\t\t";
       echo '<img src="'.$images[$i].'" alt=""></div>'."\r\n\t";
}
```

Comment: hi your code is wrong use `$images[$i]` instead of `$image`. how about mine?(-:

Comment: Updated. Sorry, just wanted to show you how the for loop better suits the issue. Thanks for the downvote?

Comment: now both of the answers should be correct. thanks for your edit now +1 to you.(-: