# Using glob to dynamically display images with different extensions not working in PHP

Tags: php, image, foreach, glob

my first question here...
I'm trying to display the images dynamically from a folder inside a "[fotorama](http://fotorama.io/)" div. With this code:

```
<?php
$dir = "/example/images/category/";
$images = glob($dir.'*.{JPG,jpg,gif,png,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo "<img src='".$dir.".".$image."' />";
};?>
```

I know this have been asked before; but after reading everything I found: For example ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613630/using-glob-to-display-images-from-a-directory-while-echoing-a-unique-first-im), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767897/using-glob-to-display-images-but-images-wont-display) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518403/using-glob-to-get-all-images-from-a-directory)) plus many other "similar" questions.
They all recommend pretty much the same code (with slight differences in syntax between each other) 
I've tried every variant of this code I've found but it displays nothing.

I know the ($dir) is fine, because when I try:
`echo '<img src="'.$dir."img1.jpg".'">';` It displays that particular image. The problem must be in the glob part because when I use `var_dump($images);` before the foreach loop it shows this: array (0) {}.

I don't know what is the problem...

Edit: 
With help from Sam's answer, the code now works I found out I had forgotten to correct something in the `GLOB_BRACE` part. The corrected code should be something like this:

```
<?php
$dir = "c:/xampp/htdocs/example/images/category/";
$images = glob($dir.'*.{JPG,jpg,gif,png,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo "<img src='".$image."' />";
};
?>
```

For future reference the path on Xampp localhost for the `glob()`function to work is: `C:/xampp/htdocs/your-folder-structure`

Comment: What's the exact directory? Because `/example` would be a filesystem-absolute path, not a docroot-relative one. Enable error_reporting.

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention that I'm on Xampp the path is simply htdocs/example/images/category.

I don't know how to enable error_reporting... 'I'll start looking for that right know.

Comment: You just need to ensure your path is reachable from the current working directory. If `glob()` can't find it, then it returns an empty array (regardless of the file extension pattern).

Comment: Well, that little code is on "gallery.php" which is inside the "example" folder, I'm pretty new to PHP but I assume that path is accessible from there. (I've also tried /images/category/)....

I guess error_reporting is enabled, (Or so I think) because in some of the many attempts it did showed different errors. Many of them related to the `echo` part of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob()` looks for a filesystem path, whereas the `src` attribute of the image tag is pointing at a url location, probably relative to your docroot (but could be anywhere depending on your routing rules).

So, for example, if the `/example/images/` url points to `/var/www/example/images/` on the filesystem, you'd want to do:

```
<?php
$dir = "/var/www/example/images/category/";
$url = "/example/images/category/";
$images = glob($dir.'*.{JPG,jpg,gif,png,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo "<img src='{$url}{$image}' />";
};?>
```

You'll need to figure out where on the filesystem that directory is in your specific case though.

Comment: Hi Sam! 
I fixed some issues your answer was right! I've got a related problem: 

The `var_dump($images);`  now throws an array like this: `array(3) { [0]=> string(53) "c:/xampp/htdocs/example/images/category/img1.jpg" [1]=> string(53) "c:/xampp/htdocs/example/images/category/img2.jpg" }` 

This `<img src='".$image."' />` echoes this `<img src='c:/xampp/htdocs/example/images/category/img1.jpg' />` the images fail to display because it has to be something like `<img src='file:///c:.` 

Although I know this shouldn't be a problem on a server I'd like to use the $url part you used.

Comment: sorry to bother you... could you help me clarify something with the comment above?

Comment: Glob is giving you absolute paths, so you can just set `$url = "file:///";` if you want to access the images locally. If you want to access them through the webserver you'll still need to figure out what URL the images are being served on.

Comment: Thanks, what I did was:

    `foreach ($images as $image) {
    $imagename = basename($image);
    echo '<img src="'.$url.''.$imagename.'" />`

Comment: Might be best to update your question with that solution for others to benefit from then. :)